# Monopoly probabilities landing on the same tile 12 times in a row

Tags: probability-theory, recreational-mathematics

Hi! I have one rather unusual question. Couple days ago, me and my friends played a game of monopoly. And something happened that you don’t see every day: my friend landed on the same jail box every single time, he just couldn’t go past jail tile 12 times in a row. I want to ask, whats the mathematical probabilities of this event happening to someone again?

[image: Monopoly board]

Comment: First, I would figure out the probability of ending up in jail, in general!

Comment: I forget the size and layout of the board.  Do you mean that he got out of jail somehow but his next throw took him to the Go To Jail square?  What throw does that?

Comment: I don't think that is a good approach. Karolis doesn't want the probability of going to jail 12 times, they want the probability of landing on a certain square 12 times. There are several ways to go to jail, only one involves landing on the square.

Comment: In general, I don't think that you can land on the same square even twice in a row since the maximum throw of 12 is not enough to loop the board.

Comment: Noo, he went to a jail tile 12 times in a row, throwing two or three times. What is a probability going to that tile everytime you are near, probability of doesn’t skipping it.

Comment: Karolis: It's not clear to me what event you say happened 12 times in a row.  What happened exactly?

Comment: Every single time, going from start, my friend rolled 3 or 4 times and went to exactly same tile, the jail tile. For example: I play and in 3 or 4 turns I roll out a combination that places me on a jail tile, then I come to the start, do everything the same and come to the jail tile again. That happened 12 times in a row. That should be more clear.

Comment: When you say "the jail tile" do you mean the "Just Visiting" tile?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the person was in Jail at some point, got out, moved 20 spaces over the course of a few turns, which landed them on Go To Jail. They then repeated this a dozen times, moving over the same half of the board between Jail and Go To Jail repeatedly. It's not exactly landing on the same space 12 times "in a row", as it can take place over multiple turns. I think the question boils down to the probability of moving exactly 20 spaces in multiple turns, and repeating 12 times.

Comment: Yes! Exactly, could someone calculate that probability because we tried and couldn’t calculate it!

Comment: So, he does not immediately get out of jail and go straight back in.  I was wondering how that would happen but it managed to land on Go To Jail when he next passes it.

Answer (score 1):

We're looking for the probability of starting in Jail, moving exactly 20 spaces around the board to land on Go To Jail, and repeating 12 times.

To approximate the likelihood of moving exactly 20 spaces over an indeterminate number of rolls, I simulated 10 dice rolls (the max it would take to move 20 spaces), and checked whether the cumulative sum was 20 spaces at any point. I repeated this 1 million times, and found that a person rolling two dice will move exactly 20 spaces about 14.1% of the time. That is, when starting from Jail and rolling normally, you stand a 14.1% chance of landing on Go To Jail before making it any further.

The likelihood of doing this 12 times is simply 0.141 ^ 12, or 6.17 x 10^-11, somewhat less likely than one in ten billion. It's extremely unlikely that this would happen to you, although given that there are a quarter billion Monopoly sets, each of which is possibly played multiple times by multiple people with multiple trips around the board, it's reasonably likely that this has happened to *someone* in the history of Monopoly.

These probabilities assume that the player pays to get out of jail and is rolling normally, and does not require doubles to escape jail. The distribution of likely spaces will change somewhat if we require that the first roll must be doubles. I also don't account for any other means of going to jail, like rolling doubles three times in a row, or getting a Chance card that sends you there. It also does not account for any Chance/Community Chest cards that would move you elsewhere on the board, as it assumes that all movement is done as a result of the dice roll.

Comment: 29% does indeed seem like a lot, especially given that you'd expect all the nearby spaces to have approximately the same chance of being landed on, which we wouldn't expect given that a player moves 7 spaces on average when throwing two dice. My calculations produced 514655831864269/3656158440062976, or about 14.1%, and that probability converges to 1/7 as the target space is farther and farther away, as I would expect. (Hopefully I'm not misremembering the rules to Monopoly.)

Comment: @dfan Thanks, you are correct - I had a coding error where I looked at each die roll individually, rather than rolling them in pairs! Fixing the text now.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, since a single die roll is 3.5 on average and 29% is about 1/3.5.

Comment: Hooooly, so you say that my friend was 1 in a couple billion, because I am sure, he went to jail 12 times in a row. Thanks guys!!